# Add Data frame in flutter python framework Or how to connect python code with flutter

Tags: python, flutter

can we add Data frame in flutter python framework  and show them in tables format Or how can we take another python script data into our flutter python framework.

Answer (score 0):

Running python directly in flutter isn't possible (yet). However there are few things that you could try:

- Screenshot the data frame
- Host a Webserver and create a WebView to point to that

If you need it to be interactive, use the WebView.